# How can I restore (re-attach to) a screen started using crontab @reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, screen, restore

I have started a crontab job at reboot using the following command:

```
@reboot /opt/myapp/autostart_hub.sh
```

The file "autostart_hub.sh" has the following single-line command:

```
screen -d -m -S hub /opt/hubb/hub --conf  /opt/hubb/hub_conf.yaml
```

The program, hub, is working correctly. However, **I am not able to re-attach to the screen**. Even when I execute:

```
screen -ls
```

as root or normal user (user1), it says:

```
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-user1.
```

***OS: UBUNTU 14.04***

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let screen know where you want the sockets to be placed. Seems like the environment from which you are calling (cron) differs from the one after login (missing/different HOME, I suppose). Add the following at the beginning of your /opt/myapp/autostart_hub.sh script:

```
export SCREENDIR=/var/run/screen/S-root
```

Now you should be able to reconnect detached screens in a convenient way.

You can also direct screen to look for sockets in a different directory upon reconnect:

```
# SCREENDIR=/.screen -r
```

Comment: Dear Stefan, thank you very much for your solution. It was helpful. And by the way, after upgrading to UBUNTU 16.04 I did not have the problem, too.